# Can I remap the "," command in VIM before using it as the leader key?

Tags: vim, key, leader

I like the way of working with "," as a leader key, but
don't want to lose the original "," functionality, because it is very powerful with the "f" and "t" command.

Is there a way I can remap the original "," key, maybe invoking some internal low level VIM call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. By using `:nnoremap`, you can define a *non-recursive mapping*; i.e. the right-hand side isn't checked for mappings, so the original meaning of `,` is still accessible. For example, I remap `'` for this (as the *jump to mark* functionality of `'` is also and almost identically available with the `` ` `` command):

```
:nnoremap ' ,
```

Comment: Thanks! The solution is easier than I thought!